# At what altitude did the Skylab space station disintegrate?

Tags: reentry, skylab

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab) it is written that SkyLab's reentry began at 16:37 UTC on July 11, 1979. But neither on the page nor in the source is it written how high the Skylab workshop started disintegrating. It is written that at 148 km (92 mi) the workshop's alignment got adjusted one last time for reentry. Do we have any detailed record(s) of SkyLab's descent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a detailed reconstruction in [NASA Technical Memorandum 78308 Skylab Orbital Lifetime Prediction and Decay Analysis](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19810005468)

> The assumed Skylab breakup scenario was as follows:
>
> - The OWS SAS array (aerodynamically) off at 62 nmi.
> - The ATM separates from the remaining OWS at 54 nmi.
> - ATM SAS arrays separate from the vehicle between 54 to 50 nmi
> - ATM and OWS breakup at 42 nmi

I believe the use of the word "assumed" means that this is what they took to happen when reconstructing the trajectory.

Acronymology

- ATM Apollo Telescope Mount
- nmi Nautical Miles
- OWS Orbital Workshop
- SAS Solar Array System

Comment: @RussellBorogove thanks for the edit. ntrs changed their interface and I was a bit lost.

Comment: nmi?  Just to clarify.

Comment: @OscarLanzi "nmi" is a funny way to disambiguate nautical miles from nanometers, and it's necessary because NASA learned the expensive way to be 105% clear about the units of measurement.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yeah, I was thinking "nanomiles"?

Comment: To within an order of magnitude, a bacterium is about a nanomile in diameter.